# O link da minha DIV principal não funciona se eu tiver um link em minha DIV interna

Tags: javascript, css

tenho uma DIV dentro de outra, porém a minha DIV principal não funciona o link se eu colocar dentro dela uma DIV com link para fechar.

**CSS:**

```
#guaraparivirtualsuperpopup {
    position:relative;
    width:1215px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#000000;
    /* background-image:url(http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/Lay_Out/dr-bruno.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    */
    margin: 0 auto;

    border: 1px solid #EA8419;
}
#guaraparivirtualsuperpopupbtn {
    width:100px;
    height:36px;
    background-image:url(http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/img-novo/fechar.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:right;
    position: relative;

}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function superpopgv(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup) {

    if(document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```

**DIV´s**

```
<a href="<?php echo $linkbannerrt; ?>" target="_blank" title="Super Pop-Up" / >
<div id="guaraparivirtualsuperpopup" style="background-image:url(superpopup/<?php echo $rt; ?>);">


<a href="#" onclick="javascript: superpopgv('guaraparivirtualsuperpopup');" />
<div id="guaraparivirtualsuperpopupbtn"></div>
</a>

</div>
</a>
```

Seu eu coloco este link

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: superpopgv('guaraparivirtualsuperpopup');" />
```

O link abaixo não funciona

```
<a href="<?php echo $linkbannerrt; ?>" target="_blank" title="Super Pop-Up" / >
```

Como fazer para resolver?

Answer (score 1):

O link a que você se refere não está **abaixo** do outro link e sim **DENTRO** do outro link.

Coloquei em tags separadas... Veja o trecho de código abaixo:

```js
function superpopgv(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup) {

       if(document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

```css
#guaraparivirtualsuperpopup {
    position:relative;
    width:1215px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#000000;
   /* background-image:url(http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/Lay_Out/dr-bruno.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    */
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #EA8419;
}
#guaraparivirtualsuperpopupbtn {
    width:100px;
    height:36px;
    background-image:url(http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/img-novo/fechar.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:right;
    position: relative;

}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.testedolink.com.br/" target="_blank" title="Super Pop-Up">Link 1</a>

<div id="guaraparivirtualsuperpopup" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-h-c-207-324-10.jpg);">


<a href="#" onclick="javascript: superpopgv('guaraparivirtualsuperpopup');" >
<div id="guaraparivirtualsuperpopupbtn">Link2</div>
</a>

</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida é só postar um comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode colocar um link  dentro de outro link  diferente.
Por especificações de HTML existente pela w3, você não pode. Esta restrição realmente foi aplicada por navegadores HTML5.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element

Talvez seja melhor você montar a sua tela de outra forma.

Comment: Essa pode ser a identificação do erro, mas não é um resposta que solucione o problema. Você pode mover seu comentário para o respectivo campo de comentários.

Comment: Rafael vc não está confundindo, através do link que postou, o elemento ""link", com o elemento "a" ?